# How do you do partial wave analysis with spin?

Tags: angular-momentum, scattering

The derivations of the partial wave expansion I've seen have assumed spinless particles. However, when spin is involved, $l$ (orbital angular momentum) is no longer a good quantum number. What are some good resources to learn about doing partial wave analysis with spin involved?

Edit: A better formulation of my question is, when people refer to the $l$-th partial wave of a quantity (say the phase shift) when $L$ is not conserved, are they referring to only the diagonal part of that quantity?

Comment: One can use total angular momentum $\vec J =  \vec L + \vec S$ whenever $l$ is no longer a good quantum number and any textbooks discussing scattering phenomena usually have the partial-wave topic covered too!